# 0 - Using $this when not in object content

Tags: php, update, php7

I moved a website from server (PHP 5.6.38) to localhost (PHP 7.2.10). And I receive this error in the page title (in the chrome tab):

> 0 - Using $this when not in object content

While searching online I found that I have to replace all instances of `JSite::getMenu()` with `JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()`, I did it with no luck. I changed the theme and the error dissapeared, so its probably something with the theme. I tried to edit the theme but I receive this error :

> An error has occurred.
>
> 0 syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting
>   elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)
>
> Return to
>   Control Panel

But there is no information where this error is.

I downloaded again the template files from server, replace the local ones but still get the same error, while on the live server there is no such error

**EDIT**

I enabled `error_reporting` and I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:...\html\modules.php on line 64

The problem is that the file is identical with the one on the server and on the server I dont get any error...

Here is the code:

```
function modChrome_myCatMod($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    $moduleTag      = $params->get('module_tag', 'div');
    $headerTag      = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_tag', 'h3'));
    $bootstrapSize  = (int) $params->get('bootstrap_size', 0);
    $moduleClass    = $bootstrapSize != 0 ? ' span' . $bootstrapSize : '';

    // Temporarily store header class in variable
    $headerClass    = $params->get('header_class');
    $headerClass    = ($headerClass) ? ' class="' . htmlspecialchars($headerClass) . '"' : '';

    if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
        <<?php echo $moduleTag; ?> class="moduletable<?php echo htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) . $moduleClass; ?>" id="Mod<?php echo $module->id;?>">
            <?php if ((bool) $module->showtitle) : ?>
                <?php $com_content_categories = $params->get('com_content_categories'); if(!empty($com_content_categories)): 
                    $caturl = ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute ( $com_content_categories[0] );
                ?>
                <<?php echo $headerTag . $headerClass . '>' ?><a href="<?php echo $caturl;?>"><?php  echo $module->title; ?></a></<?php echo $headerTag; ?>>                                                    
                <?php else : ?>             
                <<?php echo $headerTag . $headerClass . '>' . $module->title; ?></<?php echo $headerTag; ?>>                    
                <? endif;?>

            <?php endif; ?><?php echo $module->content; ?>
        </<?php echo $moduleTag; ?>>
    <?php endif; 
}     //////////////////////////////////error line
```

Comment: Enable Debug in Global Configuration to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: What is the version of Joomla? does the backend work correctly with you?

Comment: ...and what is the theme that you are using?

Comment: It looks very likely you have outdated Joomla or old extensions - which aren't compatible with php 7.2x. Why did you move to localhost? I guess for updates or other development. In such cases, it is better to initially clone the site in a similar environment to start your tasks (updates etc) and then update your PHP. As for the new error - about the elseif - you need to enable debug. If you only made any changes in your template, then probably the problem is somewhere in there, and it may be easy to spot it by reading the code.

Comment: @MohamedAbdelaziz in localhost (php 7.2.10) I updated joomla to 3.9 backend works without any problem.

Comment: @Sharky I enabled debug (i can see the asterisks in backend) but nothing changes in the frontend

Comment: @FFrewin I moved to localhost in order to check the updates (php, joomla, plugins). In Wordpress is easy to check which plugin causes the problem because there are not many, in Joomla I have more than 8 pages of plugins and modules. Is there a way to find the faulty one (if any) without disabling all of them and enabling back one by one?

Comment: If you have Error Reporting in your Global Configiration set to `development` it should provide a stack trace

Comment: @mickmackusa the template is https://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/ja-teline-v v:1.1.1 customized

Comment: @dvn22 - Update the template to v1.1.4 and also ensure you have the latest version of the T3 plugin (v2.7.4). You can view the downloads here: https://www.joomlart.com/member/downloads/joomlart/joomla-templates/ja-teline-v

Comment: @Lodder the problem is that the template is heavily modified and I am not the one who did that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote me on this but I have a feeling it may be due to the mixing of curly braces and alternative syntax.

I've rewritten your modChrome using curly braces:

```
function modChrome_myCatMod($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    $moduleTag      = $params->get('module_tag', 'div');
    $headerTag      = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_tag', 'h3'));
    $bootstrapSize  = (int) $params->get('bootstrap_size', 0);
    $moduleClass    = $bootstrapSize != 0 ? ' span' . $bootstrapSize : '';

    // Temporarily store header class in variable
    $headerClass    = $params->get('header_class');
    $headerClass    = ($headerClass) ? ' class="' . htmlspecialchars($headerClass) . '"' : '';

    if (!empty ($module->content))
    {
        echo '<' . $moduleTag . ' class="moduletable' . htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) . $moduleClass . '" id="Mod' . $module->id . '">';
            if ((bool) $module->showtitle)
            {
                $com_content_categories = $params->get('com_content_categories');

                if (!empty($com_content_categories))
                {
                    $caturl = ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($com_content_categories[0]);
                    echo '<' . $headerTag . $headerClass . '><a href="' . $caturl . '">' . $module->title . '</a></' . $headerTag . '>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<' . $headerTag . $headerClass . '>' . $module->title . '</' . $headerTag . '>';
                }

                }
            echo $module->content;
        echo '</' . $moduleTag . '>';
    }
}
```

Hope this solves the issue.

That said, if you have not provided the entire contents of this file in your question, I'd suggest doing so as the error may actually derive from a different line.

Comment: Ah nice. Glad it worked :)